# Script configuration issues

Tags: scripting, sudo, users, solaris, error-handling

My purpose is to allow user A to run a specific script owned by user B but with user B’s profile loaded. This is on a Solaris maachine.

I have users A and B, I set this line: in the sudoers file, so that A can get B's permission then run this `script.sh`:

```
A ALL= (B) /tmp/script.sh
```

The command `sudo -u B /tmp/script.sh` can run, but running it with the `–i` flag to load user B’s profile fails:

```
$ sudo -i -u B /tmp/script.sh
command not allowed: /bin/sh –c /tmp/script.sh
```

I need this –i because I want to load user B’s profile, which is different to user A's. Is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I'm afraid we don't allow multiple questions on a single post. I have removed your second query, please post it separately as a new question.

Comment: As per my understanding of the sudo man page, `-i` requires you to give the target user the rights to run a shell. That looks like overkill for your current requirement. As a workaround, could the script be modified to source the profile directly? Can you try this and see if it works?